# Convert Topic-name and Description in pandas into Topic-Name, Words and Frequency

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have a pandas data-frame consist of Topic-Name,Description

[image: Original Data]

I am trying to convert it into Topic-Name, Word (appeared in Description Column) and its Frequency

[image: Expected Result]

I have tried this but it only gave me word and frequency for Descriptions, not on Topic-Name Level.

```
import nltk
top_N = 4
a = df['ParsedText'].str.cat(sep=' ')
nltk.download('punkt')
words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(a)
word_dist = nltk.FreqDist(words)
rslt = pd.DataFrame(word_dist.most_common(top_N),
                columns=['Word', 'Frequency'])
print(rslt)
```

- Parsed Text is a Description Column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
(df.assign(Description=df.Description.str.split()).explode()
   .groupby('TopicName')['Description'].value_counts()
   .reset_index(name='Frequency')
)
```

Comment: TypeError: explode() missing 1 required positional argument: 'column'

output = pd.DataFrame(df.assign(ParsedText=df.ParsedText.str.split()).explode()  .groupby('ID')['ParsedText'].value_counts().reset_index(name='Frequency'))

Comment: Pass ‘Description' to explode.

Comment: Its working for me after passing argument to explode. Can I exclude Stop Words for each description?

Comment: insert `.loc[lambda x: ~x['Description'].isin(list_stop_words)]` after `.explode('Description')`. But you should consider some sort of tokenization, e.g. from `nltk`.

Comment: Thank you. The above solution helped.